# Kubuntu -- show notifications on primary monitor

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, notification

I am on Kubuntu 20.04 with dual monitor setup. The primary monitor is to the right. But notifications -- such as incoming gmail messages -- show on the secondary monitor, which is to the left.
How can I get those notifications to show on the primary monitor?